# How reliable is Raku's is-prime function?

Tags: primes, raku

The [documentation](https://docs.raku.org/routine/is-prime) for Raku's `is-prime` function says the following:

> Returns True if this Int is known to be a prime, or is likely to be a
> prime based on a probabilistic Miller-Rabin test.
>
> Returns False if this Int is known not to be a prime.

I do a lot of code golfing in Raku, and it's very convenient for many problems to have a built-in way to test for primality.  For example, to obtain a lazy infinite sequence of prime numbers:

```
my @primes = grep &is-prime, ^Inf;
```

However, occasionally I've been bothered that the documentation says something other than "Returns True if this Int is prime, and False otherwise."  In fact, the wording seems to admit of possible false positives or false negatives.

How reliable is `is-prime`, really?

Comment: *"Returns False if this Int is known not to be a prime."* IOW, there are no false negatives. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_pseudoprime

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Raku uses the Miller-Rabin primality test, a test where a potential prime is checked if it's likely to be prime in different bases, and the more bases it's likely to be prime in, the more likely it is to be actually prime. This has an accuracy of at least 1 − 4<sup>−*k*</sup>, where *k* is the number of iterations run. I wasn't able to find the actual number of iterations that Raku runs, probably very many. But regardless, the general sentiment around the Miller-Rabin primarily test is that it's good enough for practical usage, but don't use it for anything that is cryptographic or otherwise security-related.

I would personally say good enough for code golf, - it's a language feature, and if people wanted to be picky about it, then you could write your own version of Raku which is completely identical except with the primality test replaced with a true prime test.

Comment: Miller-Rabin is commonly used in cryptography and security-related applications. Also, the question is about *reliability*, so the knowing the number of iterations used to critical to answering the question.

Comment: FWIW, aiui, `is-prime`'s reliability is an implementation detail of each backend. The github blame right now for C code related to [`is-prime` in MoarVM](https://github.com/MoarVM/MoarVM/blame/6adfc376cb8e288368620254bdd34d99244507d5/src/math/bigintops.c#L1516-L1579) shows it generally calls `mp_prime_is_prime(ia, 40, &result)`. I think the `40` is the number of interations, and the `mp_prime_is_prime` ultimately calls [`mp_prime_strong_lucas_selfridge` in libtommath](https://github.com/libtom/libtommath/blob/03de03dee753442d4b23166982514639c4ccbc39/mp_prime_strong_lucas_selfridge.c#L51-L279).

Comment: @raiph 40 iterations? Someone get them a Frobenius test ASAP!

Comment: @Charles Maybe you can help? I don't know C but perhaps you can take a quick gander at [the `is-prime` code in MoarVM](https://github.com/MoarVM/MoarVM/blame/6adfc376cb8e288368620254bdd34d99244507d5/src/math/bigintops.c#L1516-L1579) and comment on the "Forišek and Jančina" code at the start, and then at [the libtommath commit that introduced `mp_prime_strong_lucas_selfridge` **and** the "Frobenius test" you mention](https://github.com/libtom/libtommath/pull/113). So does it look to you like MoarVM's `is-prime` is a solid contemporary implementation?

Comment: @raiph Forišek & Jančina is solid for 32-bit. For 64-bit, BPSW has no counterexamples and may be faster. LibTomMath, the source of the `mp_prime_is_prime` call, can be set up to do deterministic Sorenson-Webster checking for numbers below 3317044064679887385961981; this is very slow (13-14 M-R tests) but perfect, so possibly relevant to inputs between 65 and 81 bits. (This is not currently used in is-prime.)

Comment: @raiph At the moment, the code is efficient up to 32 bits and beyond there it does 42 M-R tests, plus a strong Lucas-Selfridge test if `LTM_USE_FROBENIUS_TEST` is set and `LTM_USE_ONLY_MR` is unset. But this is not reasonable at all; even if for some reason you wanted an error probability of 1 in 10^24, it would be much more efficient to use Frobenius tests. Running `mp_prime_frobenius_underwood` after BPSW would fulfill all practical needs, but to get 1 in 10^24 you're going to need parameterization which that test lacks.

Comment: @raiph 7 runs of Seysen's [SQFT](https://eprint.iacr.org/2005/462.pdf) has maximum error 1 in 10^25 and only takes as long as 14 M-R tests. So that would already be a factor of 3 speedup. But if you only need good average performance many fewer runs are needed, maybe just 2, and that's much more significant.

Comment: Actually just 5 runs of SQFT3 would suffice, at time ~11 M-R tests. So that's more like a factor of 4 speedup.

Comment: @Charles Thank you! I have drawn this info to core devs' attention. If they do not comment on it I will file an issue with your commentary. Again, many thanks.

Comment: @raiph Thank you! I don't know anything about the project in particular but if you need something else just ping me.

Comment: I brought it up years ago, and even had a local branch using BPSW.  It was **much** faster than the code at that time as well as being arguably better quality (guaranteed correct for 64-bit inputs, deterministic and at least as good as Pari etc. for larger).  But life intervened before it got presented or committed. :(

Comment: Hi @DanaJ, and thanks for having done that and for commenting here. FTR [here's discussion by you about your branch in 2013/2014](https://irclogs.raku.org/perl6/search.html?type=words&nicks=danaj), including this comment towards the end of that period: "I still have more testing, cleanup, and API discussion, but looks like my new is-prime is running ~20x faster than the current one."

Comment: Hi again @Charles, .@DanaJ. My guess is there's an extremely low likelihood, at least for the foreseeable future, that MoarVM's `is-prime` will stop using LTM functions (presumably `mp_prime_is_prime`). Please consider whether you have helpful comments to add to .@deamentiaemundi's new answer (preferably below their answer) and/or to [the pending PR they linked](https://github.com/libtom/libtommath/pull/541). .@DanaJ, you may be amused to see a comment by the PR's author: "It took a bit but I found it: this has been promised in a comment in #498. But what are [N] years between friends?"  

Answer (score 4):

According to its source (rakudo-star-2023.02-01.tar.gz, SHA3-256 digest: a924ebcbb78f979511331ed2a841cba88529f6b43a13c9d04692a93fee93672a) it uses LibTomMath's `mp_prime_is_prime` function. If compiled out of the box for anything larger than 8-bit architectures, it uses the following tests for input `N` and `t = 0`:

- is `N` even
- is `N` a perfect square
- trial division with the first 255 primes
- two rounds of Miller-Rabin with bases two and three respectively
- a strong Lucas test with the Selfridge parameters `D = 5`, `P = 1` and `Q = (1-D)/4`
- one Miller-Rabin test with a random base `b <= N`

For 8-bit architectures (be aware that LTM stopped supporting 8-bit!) it replaces the strong Lucas test with a Frobenius test written by Paul Underwood.

This function is safe for cryptographic purposes.

It has a compile-time variant to use Miller-Rabin tests only which is not, I repeat: NOT safe for cryptographic purposes! It uses MR tests with bases two and three after all of the preliminaries described in the list above and one MR test with a random base.

With input `N <= 3317044064679887385961981` and `t < 0` it uses the findings of Sorenson and Webster for a deterministic prime test up to and including `3317044064679887385961981`.

(Note for transparency: I am the author of the described BPSW enhancement of `mp_prime_is_prime` in LibTomMath)

This function is a bit old (no 8-bit support anymore) and convoluted. There is [a new pull request](https://github.com/libtom/libtommath/pull/541) that replaces the strong Lucas test with an extra strong Lucas test with Baillie's parameters `P = 3` and `Q = 1` and the Frobenius-Underwood test has been made a compile time addition, placed after the extra strong Lucas test.

I don't know how Raku handles 3rd-party updates but the author of MoarVM is a regular at LibTomMath.